# Group(Partition) lazy sequence by key

Tags: clojure

I have a lazy sequence of maps :

```
{:a 1 :b "a"} {:a 1 :b "b"} {:a 2 :b "a"} {:a 3 :b "a"} {:a 3 :b "b"} ...
```

and I want to group it by key :a and return another lazy seq:

```
[{:a 1 :b "a"} {:a 1 :b "b"}] [{:a 2 :b "a"}] [{:a 3 :b "a"} {:a 3 :b "b"}] ...
```

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
user=> (def a [{:a 1 :b "a"} {:a 1 :b "b"} {:a 2 :b "a"} {:a 3 :b "a"} {:a 3 :b "b"}])
#'user/a
user=> (group-by :a a)
{1 [{:a 1, :b "a"} {:a 1, :b "b"}], 2 [{:a 2, :b "a"}], 3 [{:a 3, :b "a"} {:a 3, :b "b"}]}
user=> (map second (group-by :a a))
([{:a 1, :b "a"} {:a 1, :b "b"}] [{:a 2, :b "a"}] [{:a 3, :b "a"} {:a 3, :b "b"}])
```

Comment: @you, op: Notice that laziness is not of much use here. The grouping step requires a full traversal of the input sequence, no matter how few elements of the result sequence you are going to consume. I'd prefer a call to `vals` on the `group-by` result` over `map second`. Further notice that the result is unsorted. If sorting is a requirement you could `(->> a (group-by :a) (sort-by key) vals)`

Comment: or `(->> a (sort-by :a) (partition-with :a))`

Comment: @lgrapenthin - thank you, this is actually what I've been looking for. Just one small correction it should be 
    partition-by.